# Custom>TFBertMainLayer has already been registered to <class 'src.transformers.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertMainLayer'> occurring when downloading a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I've been trying to play with [PYTORCH-TRANSFORMERS](https://pytorch.org/hub/huggingface_pytorch-transformers/) pre-trained model. With everything at default in the collab template, using `torch.hub.load()` from `huggingface/pytorch-transformers` as 'model' to `bert-base-uncased`

code example

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.load('huggingface/pytorch-transformers', 'model', 'bert-base-uncased')    # Download model and configuration from S3 and cache.
```

and I'm presented with this error

```
Using cache found in /root/.cache/torch/hub/huggingface_pytorch-transformers_master
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ad22a1a34951> in <module>()
      1 import torch
----> 2 model = torch.hub.load('huggingface/pytorch-transformers', 'model', 'somethingelse')    # Download model and configuration from S3 and cache.
      3 model = torch.hub.load('huggingface/pytorch-transformers', 'model', './test/bert_model/')  # E.g. model was saved using `save_pretrained('./test/saved_model/')`
      4 model = torch.hub.load('huggingface/pytorch-transformers', 'model', 'bert-base-uncased', output_attentions=True)  # Update configuration during loading
      5 assert model.config.output_attentions == True

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in decorator(arg)
    177       raise ValueError(
    178           '%s has already been registered to %s' %
--> 179           (registered_name, _GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS[registered_name]))
    180 
    181     if arg in _GLOBAL_CUSTOM_NAMES:

ValueError: Custom>TFBertMainLayer has already been registered to <class 'src.transformers.modeling_tf_bert.TFBertMainLayer'>
```

I'm not really understanding what's going on.

Comment: I had a similar issue which I solved by removing the line @keras_serializable from the code in their library. Though I'm not sure what it does so this might be terrible advice

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to play with PyTorch version of the transformer, to get rid of the issue, you could either uninstall TensorFlow from your environment or comment out TensorFlow part in the _*init*_.py (start with if is_tf_available()) in your transformer's source code :)